# How to convert gcc -S output to C code?

Tags: c, gcc

I have a program written in C which does a lot of processing on a 2d array and i would like to optimize it regarding function calls and cache line misses.

**gcc -O3** performs really good but I would like to see what it really does or at least get an idea of it to help me do the same in the C code.

Now, the gcc -O3 -S outputs assembly and I was wondering if any of you guys know a way to get it back to C.

Or is there a way to get the output of O3 back to C code and see how it looks after optimization? Or at least a glimpse of it?

Comment: The moment when we get to the point where the compiler can optimize **and** rewrite your code for you, we did our job. We managed to get ourselves out of the coding loop and just let computers code themselves. Unfortunately, we're not there yet, so human eyes and brains are still necessary to some degrees.

Comment: You would be much better off using a profiler to identify the hot spots in your code, and then consider how to optimise these.

Comment: You are trying to "decompile" the code, which is considered as a kind of difficult task for C.

Comment: I know it's difficult but I'm out of ideas and i know there are tools that can show you some code. Thanks for answering guys :D

Comment: I don't know of any (at least free) tools capable of that. It's _terribly_ tough to accomplish because the compiler leaves pretty much no trace of what used to be C (no variable names most notably). And from that, the code is extensively transformed.

Comment: The decompiler would have to generate variable names, which can't even be done by lots of programmers.

Comment: Can't debug symbols be used to make a clearer decompilation? It should help, right?

Comment: Try `-fdump-tree-optimized`. It produces a dump file after the high-level optimizations in something that looks vaguely like C.

Comment: Thank you Marc, that actually helped. Unfortunately is too hard to read functions with big and many loops cause it generates too many labels... like 50 or so and it's easy to loose track of them.